# Why inner container is not fitting in the outer container?

Tags: html, css

```
.main
{
    background-color:#669;
    width:1200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:1000px;
}


.content
{
    background-color: #CCF;
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    margin-top:5%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

If you see the main class has width `1200px` and I want every `div` to be fit within `1200px`.

I set the width of the content class to `100%`, assuming that it will encounter `1200px` as its final limit.

But, it's not happening. It is actually extending from the main class and occupying entire page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `position: absolute;` will take it out of the normal flow and is one of the ways the element width will not be constrained by the parent.

Comment: ..and also if you really need `position: absolute` to the child element, apply `position: relative` to the parent element. this will let the child element to use the bounds of the relative parent element.

Comment: ok! It worked.. i am getting it within the container! but now, new issue!
The background color has disappeared! its like the content is overlapping the main class background color?!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `position: relative` to the container to restrict `absolute` positioned child elements not exceed it's size.

> Absolute positioning
>
> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element
>   that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes
>   up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned
>   element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a
>   positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

```css
.main
{
    background-color:#669;
    width:1200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:1000px;
    position: relative;
}


.content
{
    background-color: #CCF;
    width:100%;
    height:1000px;
    margin-top:5%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"><div class="content"></div></div>
```

Reference: [MDN - Absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)

Comment: Thanks you sir! But my question was already answered! Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

That's because the positioning is absolute, so the container out of the flow of the page and is no longer subject to its parent element.

Answer (score 0):

```
 position: absolute;
```

This means no matter what your .content class element will not be dependent on other divs . try converting this to relative or something else . That should work .